# Usar return en java

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente método:

```
public Object loginUser () {
    String soapEndpointUrl = "http://gamificacioc.com:80/ServerGIOC/webservices";
    String soapAction = "http://gamificacioc.com:80/ServerGIOC/comprovarLogin";

    //Recollim les dades dels buttons e inicialitzem variables
    String usuari = txtUsuari2.getText(); 
    String usuariContrasenya = textPassword2.getText();

   WebServiceCalls calls = new WebServiceCalls();
   Object authId = null;

    //Exemple sense recollir la info dels  butons ho tinc per probar directament sense recollir dels buttons
   // System.out.println(calls.comprovarLogin("fbarcia", "password"));

   //Recollin't la info dels buttons.
    SoapObject resposta = calls.comprovarLogin(usuari, usuariContrasenya);
     if (resposta == null)
     {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error falten dades");
     }

     else
     {
         //Si els buttons son plens verifica que sigui correcte
        authId= resposta.getPrimitiveProperty("authId");
        //authId ens dona el resultat que volem pasar per saber el tipus User

     //Enviem l'authId per poder saber que usuari es...         
     String resposta2 = calls.tipusUsuari(authId.toString()); 
     System.out.println(authId);


     //USUARIS D'EXEMPLE:
     //fbarcia password com admin
     //xingles 123456 com profe
     //mmaqueda contra com a alumne

     if(resposta2.equalsIgnoreCase("Admin")) {
        //Obrim pantalla administrador      
        pantalla_administrador v2 = new pantalla_administrador();
        v2.setVisible(true); // La fem visible
        dispose(); // així tanquem la finestra       



     }
     else if(resposta2.equalsIgnoreCase("profe")) {
        //Obrim pantalla professor          
        pantalla_Professor v2 = new pantalla_Professor();
        v2.setVisible(true); // La fem visible
        dispose(); // així tanquem la finestra

     }

     else if(resposta2.equalsIgnoreCase("pare") || resposta2.equalsIgnoreCase("alumne")) {

          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Aquest tipus d'usuari no pot iniciar sessió aquí."); 
          //Esborrem les dades
          txtUsuari2.setText(""); 
          textPassword2.setText(""); 
     }
     else {

          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No existeix aquest usuari."); 
          //Esborrem les dades  
          txtUsuari2.setText(""); 
          textPassword2.setText(""); 
     }   
     }
    return authId;

}
```

Necesito usar el authId en otra clase..

es decir el resultado de ese método.

Como puedo hacerlo?

Tengo que hacer una llamada algo así?

```
ClaseX xxxx = new ClaseX();
```

Y lo siguiente?

xxxx. ???

Gracias!

Comment: en un anterior hilo preguntaste como obtener el authId, supongo que debes  tener en la claseX private string AuthId
public String getAuthId()
        {
                return AuthId;
        }

lo siguientes es xxxx.getAuthId

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta sería la forma correcta, suponiendo tu clase se llama `Clase`:

```
   public class Clase{

        public Object loginUser () {
         ....
         return ...
        }

    }
```

primeramente instancia la clase:

```
Clase clase = new Clase();
```

y posteriormente puedes llamar el método el cual retorna un valor tipo `Object`:

```
Object myObject = clase.loginUser();
```

Comment: el tema es que no quiero llamar al loginUSer sino usar el valor del return...

Comment: @MontseMkd el valor que retorna el método loginUser() , este valor return authId;?

Comment: A ver si me explico XD

La claseY usa loginUser que retorna el valor AuthId. Y yo quiero desde la ClaseX usar ese authId para otras cosas. 

Se puede hacer?

Pero no quiero usar todo el método, solo necesito el resultado del authId que lo llama otra clase.

Comment: Es decir no necesito el método Login sino su resultado para usarlo en otra clase.

Comment: Si Montse, precisamente el valor de authId es el que obtienes al llamar loginUser(), en realidad es la forma correcta de obtener el valor en lugar de obtener el valor de una variable.

Comment: el problema es que me usa el método y yo no quiero que lo use. Sino que me extraiga el dato. Es decir quiero que me extraiga el dato que uso la claseX para usarlo en la claseY

Comment: si lo hago de esta forma estoy haciendo lo mismo en las dos clases, y necesito que en la claseY solo use esa variable, no que vuelva a usar login